# what is the difference between landing page and destinationPage in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

what is the difference between landing page and destinationPage in google analytics?
they are the same name in chinese.and they has the similar data result in diy report.but destinationPage has more reords than landing page. for example: if I select landing page, it has 4000 records , if I select destinationPage, it has 40000 records.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Seems like the difference is meantioned in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The landing page is the page where people land once they execute a search query and click on a link under search results. Even if they click a paid advertisement and once his land to a page it’s called a landing page.

Ex: type “web analysts in Sri Lanka” in Google. Then you will get some search results. So I selected “www.linkedin.com/in/isharashehan‎” page as an example. Once I click, it took me to that profile page and land on that page. That is a landing page.

The search destination page is a page where the user visits after using your internal site search box. Once they see some results as a result of the internal site search , they can click and visits to that page. Those pages call Search destination pages.

Comment: minor clarification: the landing page is the first page a visitor lands on, coming from *any* external source, not just a search engine results page. For example, if a visitor clicks on a link in an email to your site, or clicks on a link from another site. IOW, it is the very first page the visitor lands on that has your GA code on it.